# How to control iso manually in camera2, android

Tags: android

I am new in android and trying to figure out new camera2 effects. I have no idea how to control iso in camera preview manually. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `previewbuilder` first like this:

```
mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL);
```

and than

```
Range<Integer> range2 = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_SENSITIVITY_RANGE);
                    int max1 = range2.getUpper();//10000
                    int min1 = range2.getLower();//100
                    int iso = ((progress * (max1 - min1)) / 100 + min1);
                    mPreviewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY, iso);
```

`progress` is a variable for seekBar from `onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean user)` override method

Comment: Setting CONTROL_MODE with an int from INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE isn't correct. You can get lucky if the enum values line up, but it doesn't really make sense. Please use one of the actual CONTROL_MODE enums here, like CONTROL_MODE_OFF.

Comment: I am sorry, Eddy is absolutely right, i have mistaken during copying!

Comment: @user0770 can u help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68529131/camera-2-manually-checking-if-iso-and-shutter-speed-are-supported

Answer (score 16):

One way to determine if your device supports manual ISO control is to check if it supports the [MANUAL_SENSOR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES) capability.

If so, you can turn off auto-exposure by either disabling all automatics:

```
previewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_OFF);
```

or by just disabling auto-exposure, leaving auto-focus and auto-white-balance running:

```
previewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF);
```

Once you've disabled AE, you can manually control exposure time, sensitivity (ISO), and frame duration):

```
previewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME, exposureTime);
previewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY, sensitivity);
previewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_FRAME_DURATION, frameDuration);
```

The valid ranges for these values can be found from [SENSOR_INFO_EXPOSURE_TIME_RANGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#SENSOR_INFO_EXPOSURE_TIME_RANGE) and [SENSOR_INFO_SENSITIVITY_RANGE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#SENSOR_INFO_SENSITIVITY_RANGE) for exposure and sensitivity. For frame duration, the maximum frame duration can be found from [SENSOR_INFO_MAX_DURATION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#SENSOR_INFO_MAX_FRAME_DURATION), and the minimum frame duration (max frame rate) depends on your session output configuration. See [StreamConfigurationMap.getOutputMinFrameDuration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/StreamConfigurationMap.html#getOutputMinFrameDuration(int,%20android.util.Size)) for more details on this.

Note that once you disable AE, you have to control all 3 parameters (there are defaults if you never set one, but they won't vary automatically). You can copy the last-good values for these from the last CaptureResult before you turn off AE, to start with.

Comment: Could you plese help me with my question regarding `MANUAL_SENSOR` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40343626/which-kind-of-device-sopport-info-supported-hardware-level-full

Comment: Hi @Eddy Talvala . I have a question regarding camera 2 manual sensor. Could you please see it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41298161/how-to-implement-camera-brightness-changing-using-seekbar-on-camera-2-api-on-and thanks

Comment: @Eddy Talvala i'm familar with Camera1 api, hoping to start Camera2 soon,in Camera1 api,  it's possible to only set one of the supported ISO values.

Can you manually set ISO to  any value using Camera2 Api? Is it possible to get actual ISO value after taking the picture? I suppose `previewBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY, sensitivity)` is for manully setting any int you wish.

 You can get actual ISO value from data you get in onPictureTaken(byte[] data) method.

Comment: The valid range of supported sensitivity values is provided by https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#SENSOR_INFO_SENSITIVITY_RANGE .  The actually-used sensitivity is provided in the capture result for an image, in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureResult.html#SENSOR_SENSITIVITY . These will only be present for devices that support manual control or sensor setting readout: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES

Comment: @EddyTalvala can u help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68529131/camera-2-manually-checking-if-iso-and-shutter-speed-are-supported