# Which kind of device sopport INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL?

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I need try to set manually `exposure time` and `iso`.

I found that [answer on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293078/how-to-control-iso-manually-in-camera2-android), which explain that the first we need to check if divice support `HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL` and if yes it means that you can set your manual settings.

And for checking google provide a method

```
// Returns true if the device supports the required hardware level, or better.
boolean isHardwareLevelSupported(CameraCharacteristics c, int requiredLevel) {
 int deviceLevel = c.get(CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL);
 if (deviceLevel == CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LEGACY) {
     return requiredLevel == deviceLevel;
 }
 // deviceLevel is not LEGACY, can use numerical sort
 return requiredLevel <= deviceLevel;
}
```

Question is : i have checked my 3 defferent devices and all of them had `LEVEL_LEGACY`... Which means that i can't touch manual settings... But therefore i am wondering whitch devices support `INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL`?

Maybe i am cheking this in wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

All FULL devices will support manual controls (and no LEGACY device will support manual controls), so that's all correct.

However, there may be some LIMITED-level devices that do support manual controls. The more specific check is looking for the [MANUAL_SENSOR](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraMetadata.html#REQUEST_AVAILABLE_CAPABILITIES_MANUAL_SENSOR) capability.

Unfortunately, a large number of Android devices are still using older camera HALs, and can only support the LEGACY level through the camera2 API.  They may have vendor custom implementations for adjusting sensitivity, etc, via the old camera API, but those are not standard or documented in general.

Comment: Nice to hear you as far as i know you took apart with development camera2api... But it is very weird, i have tried to check hardware level and regardless of i got LEGACY level i have been trying to set iso but eventually it wasn't work... Than i found free app on play market named `a better camera` , and downloaded to the same device and this app can control iso... i have tried changed it and than check image properties and it is really were changed... How is it possible? Hardware level on the exact device doesn't allow to touch this settings...

Comment: having the same issue @AlekseyTimoshchenko were u able to solve it