# Is it possible to make camera preview fps more than 30?

Tags: android, camera, frame-rate

I tried to use camera in 30 to 60 fps. But when i set the parameters in more than 30, there was no change in fps. Is preview fps limited? 
Or is there any way to make the preview fps more than 30?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose any framerate that your camera supports. Note that you may need to reduce resolution to achieve high frame rate. On modern devices, you will be better served with the **camera2** API, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43646443/192373.

Comment: Thanks but i'm almost new in camera api now. Can i use camera 2 api easy? And one more question. I want to get each pixel's rgb data in high fps. Is there any way to make like that in old camera api or camera2 api?

Comment: You can find many tutorials online. You should learn the new **camera2** API these days, the old API is deprecated.

Comment: Most devices don't support RGB format for camera frames, neither with old API nor with the new one. Usually you get YUV data from which you can calculate RGB if needed.

Comment: Thanks for all reply. I decided to learn camera 2 api. It looks hard but if you say so, i have to learn that. I'll find tutorials but if you know good tutorials, please recommend to me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello, i've got a new problem in camera 2 api,Alex. If you know about this post, can you comment me?
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45376801/8349135)

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, prior to Camera2, Camera Preview frame rate control is different from recording. I have not seen any APK that supports more than 30 FPS in Preview Mode. According to the official Android Camera Parameter document https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#PREVIEW_FPS_MAX_INDEX, all the devices that I have tested on - up to Galaxy S8, only support to 30000. Therefore, if you don't use Camera2 you can only get up to 30 FPS.