# How to modify frame rate using camera2?

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera2

I'm trying to modify the frame rate (reduce it) so that we can do real-time operation on it. But cannot change the frame rate.

Possible solutions include :

- Changing `CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES`
- delay `setRepeatingRequest`

We need to reduce the generated frame rate passed to `Surfaceholder` so that can apply on operations in it further.

Comment: refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43628278/how-to-use-android-camera2-api-to-record-60-fps-video-with-fixed-exposure-time/43646443#43646443

Comment: CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES needs to be changed, but where do I change it?

Comment: **CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES** is read-only. You can set **CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE** but it may only be one of the *available* ranges.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested in the comment, I managed to find the solution and am answering my own question, on how I solved the problem.

We first create an object of `mPreviewRequestBuilder` and using it to modify frame rate.

```
private CaptureRequest.Builder mPreviewRequestBuilder;
// We set up a CaptureRequest.Builder with the output Surface.
mPreviewRequestBuilder
                = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(surface);
```

We can achieve changing this by creating an array of [Range](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Range) and setting this manually as mentioned below.

```
Range<Integer>[] fps = new Range[size];
```

Adding custom values to the Range class.

```
fps[0] = Range.create(2,5);
```

Once we have managed to create an array of Range, we can set the camera settings as mentioned below:

```
mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE,fps[0]);
mPreviewRequest = mPreviewRequestBuilder.build();
```

Comment: captureRequest.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_MODE_OFF);
captureRequest.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_FRAME_DURATION, mFrameDuration);

Comment: Hi, @Chinmay shah, How do i make sure if it is working or not. I tried above mention code snippet but it doesn't seem working in my case.

Answer (score 1):

```
Range<Integer> fpsRange = new Range<>(30,60);
mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE,fpsRange);
```

This code works and sets the target fps range. However I was able to set the values to 30,60 on S9 plus and it delivers around 45 FPS. Even though [30,60] is not available in ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Use this only if you are very desperate as this is not a professional answer:

Using [this](https://github.com/natario1/CameraView) application as an example I added this time delay between the capture of frames to force in an UGLY WAY the drop of fps. For example to reach a level of 4 fps aproximatelly, I added in .../kotlin/com/otaliastudios/cameraview/demo/CameraActivity.kt this try-catch snippet:

```
...
LOG.v("Frame delayMillis:", delay, "FPS:", 1000 / delay)
// This try catch forces a fps of 4fps aprox
try {
    Thread.sleep(250) // Sleep for 1000 milliseconds (1 second)
} catch (e: InterruptedException) {
    // Handle the interrupted exception
    e.printStackTrace()
}
if (DECODE_BITMAP) {
...
```

Also setting 'USE_FRAME_PROCESSOR' to true.