# reduce encoder frame rate

Tags: android, frame-rate, android-mediacodec, cameraapi2

I am tying to limit the frame rate to 5-10 fps.
The encoded frame are being sent though web-socket connection and my goal is to limit bandwidth to 1Mbps while having good quality for larger resolution.

my current attempt is:

```
    val format =
            MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MediaFormat.MIMETYPE_VIDEO_VP8, size.width, size.height)
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT,
            MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 1000000);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BITRATE_MODE,  MediaCodecInfo.EncoderCapabilities.BITRATE_MODE_CBR_FD);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 1);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5);
        format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_MAX_FPS_TO_ENCODER, 1);
encoderInput = mEncoder!!.createInputSurface()
encoderInput.setFrameRate(1f,Surface.FRAME_RATE_COMPATIBILITY_FIXED_SOURCE,Surface.CHANGE_FRAME_RATE_ALWAYS)
```

I tired both setting the frame rate in the format and on the surface but it is still not limiting it. based on this discussion [MediaCodec KEY_FRAME_RATE seems to be ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336604/mediacodec-key-frame-rate-seems-to-be-ignored/22339431#22339431)

The bandwidth does follow the bit rate set in the format but not he frame rate so the quality is bad.

so how to reduce the frame rate ? preferably in a way that support older version of android.

Answer (score 0):

The frame-rate value that you use to configure the encoder doesn't change the video stream. It is mainly a hint for the player / decoder about what frame-rate to expect.

In order to actually change the frame-rate of the video stream somebody must do a process called [sample-rate conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample-rate_conversion).

If you control the frames that are sent to the encoder,
then one way to [reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downsampling_(signal_processing)) the video frame-rate is to drop every Nth frame. But this will likely result in [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing). So, for good quality results you also need to implement a [low-pass filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter).

If the frames come from a third-party library, then look in the documentation for a way to request a different frame-rate. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53957348/how-to-modify-frame-rate-using-camera2) of doing so using the Camera2 API.