# How to set ISO and EV in Android Camera 2 API for video recording?

Tags: android, record, android-camera2

I'm implementing a camera application. It needs to allow user to control ISO and EV for taking pictures and recording videos.

For taking pictures, I use auto settings to take a picture first. And then, read the EXIF of the result picture to get the ISO and exposure value for computing a appropriate combination of manual ISO and exposure time. For instance, let's assume under the auto settings, I take a picture and find out that its ISO is 400 and its exposure time is 1/30s by reading the EXIF metadata. But the user want to use ISO 200 instead of ISO 400, according to the capture result of auto settings, I can compute when the ISO is 200, the exposure time needs to be 1/15s. And if the user also set to EV to +1, I can compute the exposure time at 1/7s. You may want to ask me why I need to compute these values by myself? This is because `SENSOR_SENSITIVITY` and `SENSOR_EXPOSURE_TIME` settings are only effective if `CONTROL_AE_MODE` is set to `CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF`. And when the AE mode is off, I need to set up the exposure settings totally manually. But there is a weird thing that I have tried `CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION` setting and it should set the expusure value(EV). But no matter in which AE modes, `CONTROL_AE_EXPOSURE_COMPENSATION` is ineffective. That is a reason why I still compute the exposure time by my own even if the ISO is manually set to auto.

The idea of taking pictures has been implemented, and it works well. But for recording videos, I don't know how to let users manually set the ISO and EV. How do I do?

Comment: Have you tried to use the solution described [in this post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28293078/how-to-control-iso-manually-in-camera2-android)